# Create a click associated with a random.choice? Turtle + Trinket.io

Tags: python, random, conditional-statements, click, python-turtle

So I'm trying to create a game that shows you 20 colors. Using random.choice the program chooses one of the colors and then gives the user a hint. I want the program to be able to remember the random.choice and then be able to tell the user yes/no when they click on a color block. This is the code currently:

This part makes it draw the color box & make a turtle button:

```
draw_square(pinky,"#F699CD",30,-170,80)
  barbiet = turtle.Turtle()
  barbiet.penup()
  barbiet.hideturtle()
  barbiet.color("white")
  barbiet.goto(-135,110)
  barbiet.showturtle()
  barbiet.onclick(barbiec)
```

This part generates the hint:

```
def barbie():
    print("your hint is 'Barbie'.")
list1 = [barbie,rose,fuscia,punch,blush,watermelon,flamingo,rouge,salmon,coral,peach,strawberry,rosewood,lemonade,taffy,bubblegum,balletslipper,crepe,magenta,hotpink]
  random.choice(list1)()
```

Here is what I'm trying to use to get the click to correspond to the random choice, but I can't get it to work:

```
def barbiec(print):
    if random.choice(list1)() == barbie():
      print("That's Right!")
    else:
      print("Try Again.")
```

This is a class project for a beginner coding class!

Comment: You'll need to save the color in a variable somewhere. `random.choice` just picks a new element each time. It's a good idea to share a complete [mcve]. Probably not a good idea to call a parameter `print` as that's a builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

Half your lines of code don't appear to be working towards your stated goal:

```
draw_square(pinky,"#F699CD",30,-170,80)
barbiet.color("white")
barbiet.goto(-135,110)
[barbie,rose,fuscia,punch,blush,watermelon,flamingo,rouge,salmon,coral,peach,strawberry,rosewood,lemonade,taffy,bubblegum,balletslipper,crepe,magenta,hotpink]
random.choice(list1)()
def barbiec(print):
if random.choice(list1)() == barbie():
```

The major standout issue is your failure to quote your color names.  Salvaging as much of your logic as I can, I believe the following roughly does what you describe as your program's function:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice, randint
from functools import partial

COLORS = [
    'gold', 'pink', 'purple', 'cyan', 'yellow',
    'aqua', 'black', 'tan', 'salmon', 'coral',
    'orange', 'red', 'brown', 'light yellow', 'beige',
    'gray', 'silver', 'light gray', 'magenta', 'hotpink',
]

DIAMETER = 35
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def create_circle(color):
    circle = Turtle()
    circle.hideturtle()
    circle.shape('circle')
    circle.shapesize(DIAMETER / CURSOR_SIZE)
    circle.color(color)
    circle.onclick(partial(evaluate, circle))
    circle.penup()
    circle.goto(randint(DIAMETER - width//2, width//2 - DIAMETER), randint(DIAMETER - height//2, height//2 - DIAMETER))
    circle.showturtle()

    return circle

chosen = None

def choose():
    global chosen

    chosen = choice(COLORS)

    print("Your hint is", chosen)

def evaluate(circle, x, y):
    if circle.fillcolor() == chosen:
        print("That's Right!")
        choose()
    else:
        print("Try Again.")

screen = Screen()
width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

circles = [create_circle(color) for color in COLORS]

choose()

screen.mainloop()
```